# If condiction in HTML with URL

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, if-statement, url

I'm trying to do an if condiction in my HTML file in codeigniter that checks the URL and if it contains part of the URL it does one thing if doesnt it does something else

For example:

My URL is

> **localhost/index.php/cart/galery1**

and when I click a photo it applies a filter with this URL

> **localhost/index.php/cart/galery1/2**

the thing is that when I click in a photo after the filter it goes to something like

> **localhost/index.php/cart/galery1/2/2**

There's a way I can do an if condiction checking the URL in my controler or my html ?

My code is something like that right now

**HTML**

```
<div id="top-industries" class="gallery">
        <div class="container">
          <h3 class="tittle">As Nossas Casas</h3>
                <div class="gallery-bottom">

                {foreach $products as $product}
                     <div class="view view-ninth">
                       <a href="galery1/{$product.cat_id}" class="b-link-stripe b-animate-go  swipebox"  title="Image Title"><img src="{$product.image}" alt="" class="img-responsive" width="330" height="219" target="_blank">
                        <div class="mask mask-1"></div>
                        <div class="mask mask-2"></div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <h2>CASA 1</h2>
                            <!--<p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.</p>-->

                        </div></a>
                    </div>
                {/foreach}
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Controler**

```
            if($cat_id){
            $data['catID'] = $cat_id;
            $data['products'] = $this->Cart_model->get_casa($cat_id);
        }
        else{
            $data['products'] = $this->Cart_model->get_products();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new .tpl igual as the other one only changing what you want to change and then change the controller to

```
if($cat_id){
            $data['catID'] = $cat_id;
            $data['products'] = $this->Cart_model->get_casa($cat_id);
            $this->smarty->view('fotos_galeria.tpl', $data);

        }
        else{
            $data['products'] = $this->Cart_model->get_products();
            $this->smarty->view('galeria.tpl', $data);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to set base_url(); here 
application\config\config.php

$config['base_url'] = 'www.yoursite url.com';

and then use this base_url() in link like this

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>galery1/{$product.cat_id}" class="b-link-stripe b-animate-go  swipebox"  title="Image Title"><img src="{$product.image}" alt="" class="img-responsive" width="330" height="219" target="_blank">
```

i think it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

To get the segment from `URL` you should use `CI`'s built-in library `URI Class`.

```
$this->uri->segment(n);

// your url - localhost/index.php/cart/galery1/2/3

$this->uri->segment(1); // returns conrtoller ie cart
$this->uri->segment(2); // returns function ie gallery1
$this->uri->segment(3); // returns 1st segment ie 2
$this->uri->segment(4); // returns 2nd segment ie 3

// you can also return default value when a uri segment is not available
$this->uri->segment(5, 0); // returns 0 because there is no 5th segment. Comes handy in condition -- will definitely help you here

// you can also use
uri_string();  // returns complete uri as a string ie cart/galery1/2/3
```

For more info read [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html).

Hope it helps you. :)